# Update multiple files python-gitlab

Tags: python, git, gitlab, python-gitlab

I want to update multiple files in my Gitlab repository using python-gitlab. I know how to update a single file but I do not want to update each file one by one.

Normally, we achieve this using these commands:

1. Make your changes
2. Git add
3. Git commit
4. Git push

Is there a way I can achieve this using python-gitlab?

```
# update a single file    
file_path = "/tmp/test1.txt"
gl = gitlab.Gitlab("https://gitlab.example.com/", private_token=access_token)
project = gl.projects.get(3278)
file = project.files.get(file_path=file_path, ref="PR")
file.content = 'new content'
file.save(branch='PR', commit_message='Update testfile')
```

Comment: How about repeating step 2 for every file you have changed?

Comment: I think my question was not clear, I've added code for updating a single file using python-gitlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took reference from here https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/commits.html

Look at this part from above link

```
# See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions
# for actions detail
data = {
    'branch': 'master',
    'commit_message': 'blah blah blah',
    'actions': [
        {
            'action': 'create',
            'file_path': 'README.rst',
            'content': open('path/to/file.rst').read(),
        },
        {
            # Binary files need to be base64 encoded
            'action': 'create',
            'file_path': 'logo.png',
            'content': base64.b64encode(open('logo.png').read()),
            'encoding': 'base64',
        }
    ]
}

commit = project.commits.create(data)
```